prove quotient mapping is open
Let $M$ be a closed subset of a normed space $E$. Then, the quotient mapping
$q: E\longrightarrow E/M$,
$x\longmapsto x+M$ is open.
and this is what my friend did
Suppose $M$ is a closed subset of a normed space $E$ and $x+M\in E/M, x\in E$.
By definition of the norm in the quotient space, consider any $\varepsilon>0$, we get:
$\inf \{\|x+m|: m\in M\}=\|x+M\|<(1+\varepsilon)\|x+M\|$.(1)
(2) Take some $m_0\in M$ such that $\|x+m_0\|\leq (1+\varepsilon) \|x+M\|$  , we have:
$q(x+m_o)=x+M.$
Put $\gamma=1+\varepsilon$. We have the mapping $q: E\longrightarrow E/M$ with $q(x+m_o)=x+M$ is linear and $\|x+m_0\|\leq \gamma \|x+M\|$.\
Then, $q$ is open.
But i questioned that why from (1) can implie (2). the (1) don't have "=" but (2) do.

This is a well-worn property of the infimum. We know that $|x + M|$ is the infimum (by definition). We also know that $(1 + \varepsilon)|x + M|$ is a number strictly greater than the infimum. Because the infimum is the greatest lower bound, and $(1 + \varepsilon)|x + M|$ is greater still, it cannot be a lower bound. Thus, there must exist some $|x + m_0|$ in this set that falls below this lower bound, i.e. where $|x + m_0| \color{red}< (1 + \varepsilon)|x + M|$. The red inequality can be weakened to a $\le$ without issue.

i got it. thank you so much
